# BPMN XOR gateway within XOR gateway allowed?

Tags: bpmn

I want to create BPMN model for online restaurant, So first I'll ask user to choose Indian or Chinese cuisine and further I'll ask user to choose which dish in that cuisine.

So, is BPMN XOR within XOR is allowed?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely legit to use multiple Xor gateways in a row. However, it depends on what you want to achieve if this is actually a smart solution. Please elaborate!